# Add repository in ubuntu12.04.2

Tags: 12.04

I have installed ubuntu 12.04.2(precise pangolin(64bit)) in VM workstation on Windows 7.
I am trying to run cmd "sudo add-apt-repository “deb http://archive.canonical.com/ maverick partner”". But it is giving me error: Need a repository.

Please reply with correct form of this cmd.Also I need to install java6 or 7 in this.

Answer (score 0):

Manually add the following line to */etc/apt/sources.list*

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ maverick partner
```

Note: it needs to be added as root. So run it with sudo - e.g.,

```
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need java7 (or 8 even 6) I suggest you to refer to this [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/java), it is reliable and it has oracle java packages for version 7 and 8 (you're able to install both without problem I think)

To add the ppa run:
`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/java`

Then
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer`
(replace the '7' with '6' or '8' as you wish)